# Cannot submit page when text field is read only

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

i have `P_ITEM`, which is Text Field. `P_ITEM` have attribute `Read-only`, when condition is true, then item is **not editable**. But i want to submit page. When `P_ITEM` is read-only, it's throws:

> Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual
> alteration of protected page item P_ITEM . If you are unsure what
> caused this error, please contact the application administrator for
> assistance.

Item don't have attriibutes `Value protected` and `Send on page submit`
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Though, there's something strange with what you say. Text items don't have "Value protected" nor "Send on page submit" properties (at least, not on the latest Apex version on apex.oracle.com). **Hidden** item has "Value protected", while **DIsplay only** items have "Send on page submit" property. So, what are you doing and what do you really have? Could you create demo application on apex.oracle.com, share developer credentials so that we could have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Set the ITEM to *READ ONLY* using javascript instead of using the apex attribute.
the javascript code is:
`document.getElementById("P_ITEM").readOnly = true;`

read this article for more details
[Resolve Session State Protection Violation Error for Display Only and Read-Only items](https://www.foxinfotech.org/resolve-session-state-protection-violation-error-in-oracle-apex)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you use P_ITEM's "Read Only"-> Type = Rows returned/Expression/.. etc. and then you update the value using Dynamic Action (DA), right?

If this is the case, you have to avoid using "Read Only" condition, because this a server-side processing and you shouldn't update value of Readonly Item with JS (DA).

Instead use another DA to make the Item readonly conditionally.

Example:
Suppose you have a decider item (e.g. P_DECIDER).
Create a Change Event on P_DECIDER and as True Action select "Execute JavaScript code".

Code:

```
if (apex.item("P_DECIDER").getValue() == "MAKE_P_ITEM_READONLY") {
    $("#P_ITEM").attr("readonly", true);
} else {
    $("#P_ITEM").attr("readonly", false);
}
```

Don't forget to turn "Fire on Initialization" ON.
You can set the return value of your "Read Only" Type Expression in "P_DECIDER" with a Pre-Rendering Process to be able to use your old condition.

Modify conditions as your need.